# Sharing database between sub-projects using Spring Boot and Liquibase

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot project with two subprojects (modules). Since the database (managed by Liquibase) is shared between two sub-projects, I would like to move the changelog and the related files to the parent project.

Parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent</name>
  <description>This is the parent for modules</description>

  <modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
  </modules>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
 </dependency>

</project>
```

Child1 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>child1</name>
    <description></description>
</project>
```

Child2 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>child2</name>
    <description></description>
</project>
```

I would like to include the configuration and properties (e.g. db changelog, database creation csv files, etc. ) in the parent project and let the parent project handle that work. However, the problem I am facing is The child projects complain regarding the changelog file and the fact that is not able to find it based on the default path. What should I do to manage database DDL within the parent project and let the child projects only deal with using the database?

Comment: When using a parent project with modules, it's best not to have any "contents" inside the parent. If you need a shared database module, create that and have both other modules depend on it.

Comment: @chrylis So you mean import that database module like any other dependencies?

Comment: Exactly so. This is a fairly common pattern generally (such as with shared DTOs between otherwise separated modules).